# Why can't I see the data in the graph?

Tags: python-3.x

i'm studying python through a book, now I'm stuck trying to make a graph that shows some data, the graph appears but I can't show that data inside the graph, the code in the book shows that the loop return must be transformed into int numbers , how do I do that? since when I try it always gives an error so I did a "try" to continue with the code and now I only get the empty graph and no data.

`import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

filename = 'sitka_weather_2014.csv'

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    hights = []
    
    try:
        for row in reader:
            hight = int(row[1])
            hights.append(hight)
    except ValueError:
        pass    
print(hights)
     

fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(hight, c='red')


plt.title('Daily high temperature, July 2014', fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Temperature (F)', fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)

plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting hight while I think you meant too hights. Now you are plotting a single data point that presents itself as an empty graph. Try adding the s and hopefully this solves the problem.

Comment: File "/Users/KKK/Desktop/python_work/hights_lows.py", line 28, in <module>
    hight = int(row[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''


if I add the S and remove the 'try' I return to the same error as before

Comment: I ment replace 'plt.plot(hight, c='red')' by "plt.plot(hights, c='red')"

Comment: IT WORKSSSSS thank you man, I was almost gave up of python haha